# Java Array compare to String

Tags: java, selenium

I just wanted to output the String from the PageSource that matches the element in an array.
What should I change on my code? Thanks a lot.

```
public void This() {        
    List<String> searchText = new ArrayList<String>();
    PageSource = driver.getPageSource();

    searchText.add("Test1");
    searchText.add("Test2");
    searchText.add("Test3");

    for (String text:searchText) {
        if (PageSource.equals(text)) {
            System.out.println(text); 
        }   
        else {
            System.out.println(text); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output and the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs correction.

You have not used any variable for PageSource(this itself is error).

Secondly, you should not compare  PageSource against a single String value instead try String operations like comparison,contains etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 array[j] = arrlist.get(j);
```

you can use either this or `toArray`
if you mean you want the desired array list to be coneverted to string
Page source cannot be compared though to string value

Answer (score 0):

You are printing in both cases whether matches or not. If you want to just print the text when it matches with `PageSource` string, remove the else part:

```
for (String text:searchText) {
    if (PageSource.equals(text)) {
        System.out.println(text); 
    }  
}
```

But if `PageSource` may contain the texts in itself, then you should use `contains(text)` instead of `equals(text)`.

```
if (PageSource.contains(text)) {
    System.out.println(text); 
}
```